# Firestore search across custom objects array

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I try to make an app on Android for services reviews, every review is save like an element in the document "user" like this-

[image: Structure in firestore]

Everytime the user save a report  I have see if inside the reports the field "plate" is existing comparing with the new one, I try query using the examples in the page [arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)

[image]

In the code i tried get with "whereEqualTo" method search by "reports.plate" or with the method "whereArrayContains" with the same field (the filter uid exits but in the first image doesn't show) any idea how i can search the document when some of the custom elements fields is equal

maybe sorry in advance for the english i'm practicing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: not yet, I decided change a little the structure, instead save all reports in an array i create a unique document for each report, and i save a 5 recent report inside of document user for first view with google cloud functions, in the two ways i always get 1 document to validate and i create or update 1 document